# force horizontal scrollbar on JScrollPane in grid bag layout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a swing JPanel using a GridBagLayout with a JLabel (image) and a JList inside a JScrollPane each taking 50% of the width.

This works well, except when I add a really long string to the JList.
Then instead of scrolling horizontally, the JScrollPane takes all of the area of the JPanel leaving a tiny image in the JLabel.

Odd thing is if I resize the window to smaller than the width of the long string, then it starts using the horizontal scroll and goes back to 50%/50% width.

How can I force the JList to always use the scroll and only take 50% of the width?

(must use GridBagLayout)

hacks welcome,

Comment: You've been long enough here to know how this site works... You come with a [mcve] and we can tell from there what's going on...

Comment: Lots of ways this might be done.  Apply a `weightx` of `0.5` or greater to each component might solve the issue.  Equally, using a `GridLayout` would achieve the same result

Comment: Have you tried using JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS ... ?

Comment: `using a GridBagLayout with a JLabel (image) and a JList inside a JScrollPane each taking 50% of the width.` - that is not how GridBagLayout works. The GridBagLayout will attempt to display all components at their preferred size. The weightx constraint is only for "extra" space. A GridLayout is for giving components equal space.

Comment: @Ansharja, that won't do anything. All that does is paint a scrollbar. It doesn't activate the scrollbar. The scrollbar only becomes active when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scrollpane. This is controlled by the layout manager since it ultimately controls the size of the scrollpane.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by setting a very small preferedSize on the scrollpane.
This seems to make it use the scroll bar for some reason and remain at 50% of the width.

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
JList list = new JList();
scroll.setViewportView(list);
parent.add(scroll, new GridBagConstraints(x,y,1,1, xWeight,yWeight, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.BOTH, insets, 0,0));
```